# While starting npm, I'm getting these error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

0 info it worked if it ends with ok

```
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]

2 info using npm@2.11.3

3 info using node@v0.12.7

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info prestart telcodna@0.0.0

6 info start telcodna@0.0.0

7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 info telcodna@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script

9 verbose stack Error: telcodna@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`

9 verbose stack Exit status 1

9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:213:16)

9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)

9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)

9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)

9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)

9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

10 verbose pkgid telcodna@0.0.0

11 verbose cwd /usr/local/node-v0.12.7/telcodna

12 error Linux 3.19.0-26-generic

13 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"

14 error node v0.12.7

15 error npm  v2.11.3

16 error code ELIFECYCLE

17 error telcodna@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`

17 error Exit status 1

18 error Failed at the telcodna@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.

18 error This is most likely a problem with the telcodna package,

18 error not with npm itself.

18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:

18 error     node ./bin/www

18 error You can get their info via:

18 error     npm owner ls telcodna

18 error
```

There is likely additional logging output above.

```
enter code here

19 verbose exit [ 1, true
```

**Please suggest me on this issue**.

Comment: Did you install nodejs ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `nodejs` command instead of `node` command this error can occur if any dependency uses `node` command.

It enters exit status after executing start script :

```
8 info telcodna@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: telcodna@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
```

You can create symlink with that command on terminal:

`sudo ln -s which nodejs /usr/bin/node`

I prefer you install node.js on ubuntu with **[nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)**. Also you will be able to have control node versions.

Comment: Thanks your reply liker korukut.